# how to find onion websites?

Tags: onion-services, help, directory, client, website

In using the `tor` browser, what websites and search engines are available for locating, in particular, `onion` websites?

Periodically, I'll see mention of such-and-such a URL for an `onion` website, but it's all too often no longer working.

Perhaps even a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/ has a large number of them. Make sure to read the sidebar for a list of search engines. You can find all contributed onion services [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/search?q=url%3A.onion&sort=new&restrict_sr=on).

The Tor project's own onion service is [here](http://expyuzz4wqqyqhjn.onion/).